# Spring Message Driven Bean and java.util.Queue

Tags: java, spring, message-driven-bean

I have some non-critical clean up operation that I want to perform inside my web-app. I'm hoping to hand it off to an asynchronous process, but I don't have any JMS provider available to me ( and I'm not likely to get one approved in the timescales ).

I like the idea of the Spring MDP, but all the examples that I have seen explicitly tie it in to a JMS implementation of some sort. Is it possible to tie it to a Queue implementation based on the java.util.Queue interface? I'm thinking that I could just push messages on to a queue and use a Spring MDP to process them.

Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use [asynchronous tasks](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html) to do the clean up. You could have a `CleanUp`component that offers @Asnyc annotated methods. The TaskExecutors implicitly use a Queue for pending tasks (like plain Java's ExecutorService). There would also be the option to collect submitted clean up requests in a Queue and let them be processed by a scheduled task.

Another alternative may be [Guava's EventBus](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained). Setting one up wth spring should be straight forward and there is an AsynchronousEventBus available.

Comment: Thanks Pyranja - that's exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) with Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed an ApacheMQ BrokerService in your application

```
<bean id="broker" class="org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService" init-method="start">
    <property name="transportConnectorURIs">
        <list>
            <value>tcp://localhost:61616</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now you can use it just as a regular ApacheMQ.